# Cannot login to Salesforce Sandbox via python API

Tags: salesforce, sandbox, python-3.7, simple-salesforce

I am using the python3.7.2 module `simple-salesforce==0.74.2` and I am having trouble trying to establish a connection to my salesforce sandbox. I can login to the salesforce production with the same credentials just fine like so:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(username='user@domain.com', password='pswd', security_token='mytoken')
```

Okay cool. Now I attempt to login to my sandbox with the following:

```
sf = Salesforce(username='user@domain.com.sandbox_name', password='pswd', security_token='mytoken', sandbox=True)
```

And I get the error:

> simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceAuthenticationFailed:
>   INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user
>   locked out.

So I tried logging in with a different method:

```
sf = Salesforce(username='user@domain.com.sandbox_name', password='pswd', security_token='mytoken', domain='sandbox_name')
```

And this gave a different error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sandbox_name.salesforce.com', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /services/Soap/u/38.0 (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8]
>   nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))

I am using a Developer sandbox, named `sandbox_name`, following salesforce's instructions. Can someone give some advice on what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved. Set `domain='test'` and generate a new token under your sandbox account

Comment: worked for me even with company domain like `company.my.salesforce.com` and a custom sandbox. email must have sandbox name appended.

Answer (score 2):

The advice here may be a bit deprecated. After a bit of tinkering, I was able to get the simple_salesforce library working with the Salesforce sandbox on a custom domain with the following code. Note the domain that I am passing to the api as well the sand_box name that needs to be appended to the username.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

USER = "user@domain.com.sandbox_name"
PASS = "pass"
SEC_TOKEN = "token"
DOMAIN = "<domain>--<sandbox_name>.<instance>.my"

sf = Salesforce(username=USER, password=PASS, security_token=SEC_TOKEN, domain=DOMAIN)
```

Comment: I was looking for this over last 5 days! You're my hero! Everything works now!

Answer (score 0):

this didn't work for me, but what did was:

```
`sf = Salesforce(
    username='my.email@test.com', 
    password='sadfd8d8d8', 
    security_token='d8d8asd8f8d8',
    instance_url='https://my-dev-org-instance-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com')`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use common domains, such as 'login' or 'test', or Salesforce My domain. If  not used, will default to 'login'.

domain parameter in API has 3 options:

1. login, which is predefined Salesforce cloud/public
2. test, that is public testing address
3. custom(Salesforce My Domain), where you can specify everything else, like custom sandbox address, and specify the prefix: before salesforce.com , in your case sandbox_name