Salesforce pulling a report using python: Error Invalid username, password, security token
Using and mirroring documentation from Github and Salesforce. Using the same credentials, I can login via web and credentials are working for other app integrations. I am trying to pull for a "lower" salesforce env. Wondering if anyone has this working? or what I'm missing.
python 3.9 venv ,pycharm,simple-salesforce is installed
vars are stored in a config file(even when I hard code it doesn't work)
Github
https://gist.github.com/rapatil/b269a347d50dc76b6fd29bec85889c28
Salesforce
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/09/how-to-automate-data-extraction-from-salesforce-using-python
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce, but I just keep getting an error 

sf = Salesforce(
, username = sf_info['username']
, password = sf_info['password']
, security_token = sf_info['security_token']
)

sf_instance = sf_info['url'] #Your Salesforce Instance URL
reportId = sf_info['new_loan_report_id']
export = '?isdtp=p1&export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv'
sfUrl = sf_instance + reportId + export

response = requests.get(sfUrl, headers=sf.headers, cookies={'sid': sf.session_id})
download_report = response.content.decode('utf-8')
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(download_report))

Error
2024-05-07 21:58:47.087 | ERROR    | main::82 - INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.

answer found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55637419/cannot-login-to-salesforce-sandbox-via-python-api?rq=2 domain = 'test'
